# Prove: If there is just one critical number, it is the abscissa at the point of inflection.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

> Prove if $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has two critical numbers their average
> is the abscissa at the point of inflection, if there is just one
> critical numbers, it is the abscissa at the point of inflection.

I've answered the first part by using the quadratic formula to get the critical numbers of the first derivative and taking the average, which gives $\frac{-b}{3a}$, which is the same as the abscissa of the inflection point obtained by setting the second derivative to zero.

I can't figure out how to prove the second part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If there only one critical point at $a$, it means that the first derivative vanishes at $a$ and that $a$ is a double root of the derivative. So $a$ has also to be a root of the second derivative.

Comment: That makes sense intuitively, and I noted that if b^2=4ac then the quadratic equation gives the desired answer: -b/3a. Am I on the right track? I can't figure out though why there being only one root (or a double root) would imply that b^2=4ac in the quadratic formula.

Comment: Or do I just argue that if there's only one root than b^2 MUST equal 4ac by definition?

Comment: If not, then having one real root, implies that there is a second one.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow the last comment.

Comment: $f^\prime$ is a polynomial of degree $2$. If $f$ has at least a critical point, $f^\prime $ vanishes at that critical point $a$. But then $f^\prime$ should have a second real root if $a$ is not a double root. And when $a$ is a root of a polynomial $g$ which is a double root, $g^\prime$ also vanishes at $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Every cubic polynomial is symmetric about its point of inflection. Also, a cubic polynomial has one and only one point of inflection. So if there is only one critical point, it must be on the point of inflection itself. Ponder!